# LDAP Query to match OU with custom keywords?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

What's the Correct Syntax for Powershell LDAP query for CN which contains the name:

> Desktops Laptops

Because the below single line of LDAP query works:

> (&(&(ou>="")(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(ou=Laptops*)))
> (&(&(ou>="")(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(ou=Desktops*)))

```
$LDAPFilter = '(&(&(ou>="")(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(ou=Laptops*)))'
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter -SearchBase 'DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com' -Properties CanonicalName | FT Name, CanonicalName -A
```

But not when I add another entry:

```
$LDAPFilter = '(&(&(ou>="")(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(|(cn=*Laptops*)(cn=*Desktops*))))'
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter -SearchBase 'DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com' -Properties CanonicalName | FT Name, CanonicalName -A
```

No result returned?

Comment: In the first query you are checking `ou=*Laptops*`, and apparently you have OU's for laptops and desktop machines. The second query tries to find machines using `cn=*Laptops*`, which would imply all your machines have a NAME including the words 'Laptop' or 'Desktop'. I think that is where the query goes wrong..

Comment: Hi @Theo, I’m trying to query multiple OU names which contains laptops and desktops. How can I achieve that using the one line LDAP query ?

Comment: What I meant was: in the second query, change `(|(cn=*Laptops*)(cn=*Desktops*))` into `(|(ou=*Laptops*)(ou=*Desktops*))`. With `cn=` you are testing the machine's name, not the name of the ou. P.S. I'm not quite sure if you need `(ou>="")` and if so, wouldn't that be `(ou=*)` ?

Comment: @THeo, yes this is working as expected. Many thanks man !

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @Theo, please turn your comments into an Answer, as you've answered this question but in the Comments.

Comment: Yes, @Theo is very good and helpful.

Comment: @T-Heron Well, as this was really not much more than a typo in the LDAP query, I think this question is perhaps better suited for a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) by [Senior Systems Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453544/senior-systems-engineer).

Comment: Hello Senior Systems Engineer, please self-answer this question with Theo's answer that he gave in the Comments, so it signposts it to others that there is an answer here.